# How to manipulate run-time setting in g++ in Parallel Mode(-D_GLIBCXX_PARALLEL) in C++ Program?

Tags: parallel-processing, g++, c++14

While reading the [GCC 4.9.0 Standard C++ Library Reference Manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/), I learnt about the uses of g++ compiler parallel support for STL algorithm. This is also proposed([N3960](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3960.pdf)) to include into the future c++ standard.

There is number of attributes which has default values set in g++(like minimum threshold limits about elements for algorithms to decide whether to use sequential or parallel). However there is interface to read/change their values. These all have been defined in the header file ***parallel/settings.h***. Most of the attributes are self explanatory as they are threshold values which decide whether our program would use parallel version of algorithm. Following is current gcc4.9 version implementation of ***struct _Settings*** constructor which set all attributes with reasonable values.

```
        algorithm_strategy(heuristic),
        sort_algorithm(MWMS),
        .........
        find_initial_block_size(256),
        find_maximum_block_size(8192),
        ...........
        workstealing_chunk_size(100),
        L1_cache_size(16 << 10),
        L2_cache_size(256 << 10),
        TLB_size(128),
        cache_line_size(64),
        qsb_steals(0),
        search_minimal_n(1000),
        find_scale_factor(0.01f)
```

However,I would like to understand about how/when to use following attributes in ***struct _Settings***?. How they should be used and when we should changes these attributes to verify how it would impact c++ program?

```
L1_cache_size
L2_cache_size
cache_line_size
```

Comment: It is often beneficial if data fits into cache, because cache is faster than RAM. If you can easily adjust your data to fit in cache, it's potentially a performance improvement. I don't see the connection to parallelism, nor do I see why one should be able to manipulate these values as they represent hardware invariants.

Comment: The first link is dead.

Comment: @Morwenn: Thanks I have fixed the broken link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This is also proposed(N3960) to include into the future c++ standard.

The contents of that draft TS are not the same as the GNU C++ library's Parallel Mode algorithms. They are based on different designs and come from different groups of people.

> How they should be used and when we should changes these attributes to verify how it would impact c++ program?

You can set the cache sizes to the correct values for your CPU, since different CPUs have different caches.

You tell the library what settings to use like this, e.g. for a CPU with 64kB L1 cache and 256kB L2 cache:

```
__gnu_parallel::_Settings settings;  // constructed with default values
settings.L1_cache_size = 64 << 10;
settings.L2_cache_size = 256 << 10;
__gnu_parallel::_Settings::set(settings);  // change global settings
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. From above explaination it appears to me that L1/L2 cache size will be applicable for parallel as well sequential version of algorithm. I was bit confused and had a impression that this settings are only applicable for paralell version as it was provided under __gnu_parallel.

Comment: It only affects the parallel mode.